# "Puff balls" mean in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Another time, Aunt Petunia had been trying to force him into a revolting old sweater of Dudley's (brown with orange **puff balls**).

I can't find *puff balls* in my dictionary, instead I found *puffball* meaning:

> a type of round white fungus that bursts to send out its seeds

I am not sure if this is really relevant. What's the **puff balls** truly meaning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something like this

[image]

[source](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/513044319/the-pom-pom-party-vtg-rmx-80s-novelty)

A sweater with woollen "puff balls" sewn onto it.  I'm not sure that I have ever heard them called puff balls before. I'd usually call them "pom poms". Of course it doesn't really matter what it looks like. You just need to know that it is a horrible sweater, and this is another example of the horrid life that Harry has.

Comment: The ones I've seen have been smaller, about the size of a shooter marble.

Comment: Could be smaller. I just found this image on etsy.